# Unpexpected Result of Division C#

Tags: c#, .net

I tried doing following:

```
Math.Log10(11/10);
```

Expected answer `0.04139268515822504075019997124302`

C# answer  `0.0`

Really strange!! Am I missing something in finding log? Need help

Comment: `11/10 = 1` because of `11` and `10` are `int`s. Use `11.0` and `10.0`.

Comment: Use `Math.Log10(11.0/10);` or use `Math.Log10(11/10.0);` ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot!! it requires typecasting. Just realised it

Comment: i'd recommend to change the title of this to something like "unpexpected result of division". That way it might help people out who have a similar problem. Right now your title is about as generic as it gets :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should put it like

```
  Math.Log10(11.0/10.0);
```

Otherwise `11 / 10` will result in ***1*** (integer division) and the logarithm in ***0*** correspondingly

Comment: writing it like Math.Log10((double)x/y) serves my purpose :)

Comment: @Nilesh Barai: Yes, the trick is to use floating point division instead of integer one; in other words you should use `double` instead of `int`. You can do it either by `(double) 11` or by `11.0` or by `11d`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calculating the log of 11/10, because 11/10 is 1. If you want to calculate it, you have to use doubles:

```
Math.Log10(11.0/10.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because it first does an integer division `11/10` (which equals 1).

Specify your numbers as double:

```
Math.Log10(11d/10d);
```

Comment: `m` - decimal, I think you meant `d`. '11d/10' is enough.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov That's right, corrected it. Decimal would be ok too, though.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
Math.Log10(11.0/10.0);
```

or

```
Math.Log10(11D/10D);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Math.Log10(11.0/10);
```